# Navigation property that depends on existing property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a class `Log` that has a property `Entity`. This entity will be a reference to some other object within the App (either `Customer`, `Supplier`, `Invoice` or `Credit`) that share a base class.

```
public class Log
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public LogCode Code { get; set; }    
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
    public string SourceID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; internal set; }
    public bool Acknowledged { get; set; }
    public EntityType EntityType { get; set; }    
    public BaseModel Entity { get; set; }
}
```

The `EntityType` property contains an `enum` that I can use to determine the type of the entity.

```
public enum EntityType
{
    Customer,
    Supplier,
    Invoice,
    Credit,
}
```

The table in the database stores the ID of this entity but as each entity type is stored in a different table I'm having difficulties gathering this entity.

I've tried modifying the setter of `EntityType` to gather the correct entity but the `Log` doesn't have any reference to the `DbContext`.

Without EF I would switch on the entity type and load the correct entity using different service objects but is there a way that I can set up entity framework to use the `EntityType` to gather the correct `Entity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should implement *Table per Concrete Type* (TPC) approach. The only one restriction: you have to use `Guid` type of `Id` instead of `int`, or leave `int`, but at this case you should assign values to it manually.

```
public abstract class BaseModel 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string SomeCommonProperty {get;set;}
}    

public class Log
{
    //other properties...
    //EntityType is not needed, but you can leave it    
    public EntityType EntityType { get; set; }
    public virtual BaseModel Entity { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BaseModel> Entities  { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Customers");
        });     
        modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Suppliers");
        });            
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
var suppliers = ctx.Entities.OfType<Supplier>()
      .Where(x => x.SupplierProperty == "1").ToList();

var supplier = (log.Entity as Supplier);
var customer = (log2.Entity as Customer);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the ID as our system isn't the one creating these entities. I'll mark this as an answer as I'm sure that in the majority of cases this will work